# MySQL SELECT with PK as key of result set

Tags: php, mysql, select

Is it possible to use `SELECT` statement in `MySQL` such that key of the result-set rows is the actual PK of table rows?

result set = PHP associative arrays

PK is auto-increment

Comment: please rephrase the question; I am unable to understand what you want to know. ;)

Comment: I just did it. But I think I made it more difficult :) But @hsz deciphered it. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native function to do that.

But you can quite easily iterate that resultset and set keys by your own.

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[ $row['id'] ] = $row;
}
```

Comment: +1 because it's likely that @Affan had this in mind but, of course, the question is pretty meaningless: result sets don't have keys (not to mention auto-incremented keys!) and nothing in MySQL defaults to `0, 1, 2...`.